# Extra character with special character received from JS

Tags: spring, tomcat, special-characters, url-encoding

My AJAX request sends a special character to a controller. Sample URL -

```
    http://localhost:8080/dataUtil/getResponse.html?param=%C2%A9%202013%20The%20New%20Times
```

param value is -**© 2013 The New Times**

Issue is that when I am decoding this parameter value at my controller, I am receiving -**Â© 2013 The New Times**

I am not able to understand from where I am getting this extra special character.

Please help regarding this.

Thanks,

Vibhav

Comment: What is your page charset encoding? It should be UTF-8

Comment: @AdamAzad the page encoding is already set to UTF-8

Comment: @VibhavSinghRohilla Which server side technology you are using?

Comment: @AdnanUmer I am using tomcat 7.0 web server and Java springs.